# Chrome Double headers sent by the server

Tags: php, google-chrome, header, download, force-download

i use php to force the download of any file and this is my code

---

**index.php**

```
<a href="download.php?file_name=example.png"><button class="details_button_T">Télécharger</button></a>
```

**download.php**

```
$file= $_GET['file_name'];
if (file_exists($file)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);
        exit();
    }
```

the code works in all browsers only **chrome** displays an error : **Double headers sent by the server**

Comment: F12 and look at the network tab, it will show you the headers so you can see which header is duplicated. Go from there. At a guess i'd say its the buffer functions causing the issue, or at least contributing to it.

Comment: You're allowing a malicious user to view **ANY** file on your server for which they know the path. `http://example.com/download.php?file_name=/etc/passwd` anyone?

Comment: dont care I'll focus on security after resolving the problem

Comment: **Lee** where i can find the headers , in network section ?

Comment: f12 dev tools > Network > select the request (will probably be the only one and will appear red i would imagine) > Select the "headers" tab (first on on the right hand box > Response Headers

Comment: i found the problem ill post the answer after 7 hours , thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**resolved**  its a little mistake

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
```

Answer (score 0):

well  is important to ensure that the propertie filename="NAME.xxx" must have doble coutes. inside de header.